# is it possible to use a switch case with and operation in C

Tags: c, if-statement, switch-statement, embedded, bitwise-operators

I need to check on multiple conditions but I don't know if I can use and operation for this particular case

here is how I want it to be:
for example if x = 0xff (I want all the cases to be considered, if x= 0xAA, i want only 1 case to be considered among all(SAY case B)

```
   switch(x)
    {
    case A && case B && case  C && Case D // all these cases will be selected if the x =0xff, if x is 0x01 , CASE A will be selected
    break;
    case B
    break;
    case C:
    break;
    default:
    break;
    }
```

any leads is appreciated

Comment: That syntax is invalid. Unfortunately, I have no idea what you are trying to do, since you haven't defined what `A`, `B`. ,`C` and `D` are. Can you explain what you want to do in words (all cases, not just one example)?

Comment: A represent a  particular enum variable, I am using it to compare, if it matches, I can do the operation I want

Comment: How can `x` be both `A` and `B` and `C` and `D` at the same time?

Comment: my requirement here is X is 0xFF, for this opcode I want case a, b , c , d to be considered and executed, where as for other op code, I want that case individually executed

Comment: You can't do what you seem to want.  Unless A == B and A == C and A == D, a single value of `x` cannot simultaneously satisfy `case A` and `case B` and `case C` and `case D` — so that's functionally ruled out (as well as syntactically).  B and C must be different to allow `case B:` and `case C:` (colons missing in code) to compile.  All in all, you need to rethink your requirements (did you mean `||` instead of `&&`, but then there are a different series of problems).  Syntactically, you can't do what your code seems to be trying to do.

Comment: @jonathan is there any other way to do other than switch case, for the opcode 0xff, I want case A, B,C,D to be executed, for opcode 0x01, Only case A, for 0X02 only case B

Comment: If A,B,C,D are enum values, do you mean to use bitwise AND, i.e. `case (A&B&C&D):`

Comment: No, I did mean by saying , I have 4 opcodes , For 1 opcode value I want four cases to happen, but for other 3 opcodes, individual cases to happen

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do — what result you actually want — so I can't suggest how you achieve it.  I'm just sure that your proposed attempt at the requisite syntax is wrong in many ways.

Answer (score 0):

Not cleanly. With `switch`, this is the nicest I can think of:

```
switch(x) {
  case 0xff:
  case 1:
    puts("A");
    if (x != 0xff) break;
  case 2:
    puts("B");
    if (x != 0xff) break;
  case 3:
    puts("C");
    if (x != 0xff) break;
  case 4:
    puts("D");
}
```

Comment: what does puts("A") does here

Comment: Prints the string  `"A"` on the standard output, as a placeholder for any task you wish to execute when `x` is either `1` or `0xFF`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your problem completly, but maybe this could help:

```
switch(x)
{
    case 0xFF:
         //do stuff of case A
         //do stuff of case C
         //do stuff of case D

    case 0xAA:
         //do stuff of case B
         break;

    default:
         break;
}
```